# How to fix .txt file that has no delimiter or space between lines

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read in logged observations from a piece of equipment that I do not have control over and the .txt log is in a less than ideal format. The file should have 3 columns per line: date, time, and observation. But the .txt file has no delimiter or space between the observation and the next date. Example:

```
11/20/20,00:00,44.411/20/20,00:05,44.411/20/20,00:10,44.6 ... and so on.
```

should ideally be formatted as

```
11/20/20,00:00,44.4
11/20/20,00:05,44.4
11/20/20,00:10,44.6
```

with a date, time and observation associated with each line. Is there a way to have pandas read this file in the way I desire?

Comment: What is the date format for months like january? IS it `1/1/20` or `01/01/20`?

Comment: @DavidErickson I'm going to assume `01/01/20` since the few entries I have for the beginning of December read `12/01/20`. I don't have any data for dates before November 20.

Comment: If you can confirm that you have fixed size records with fixed size fields, you can read the data 21 characters at a time and further split each record into 2 dates and one float.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression for finding each line:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# change s to your original text input
s = '11/20/20,00:00,44.411/20/20,00:05,44.411/20/20,00:10,44.6'

# use regular expression to findall occurrences of the pattern
data = re.findall('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2},\d{2}:\d{2},\d{2}\.\d', s)

# pass it to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                     0
0  11/20/20,00:00,44.4
1  11/20/20,00:05,44.4
2  11/20/20,00:10,44.6
```